# How can I override initial-buffer-choice if I specify a filename at command line?

Tags: init-file, customize, start-up, command-line-arguments

In my `.emacs` file I have the following line in `custom-set-variables`:

```
 '(initial-buffer-choice "~/Programming/C++/<some project I'm working on>")
```

This works great. However, I use emacs to edit lots of other files too. Before I inserted the above line in `custom-set-variables`, I could specify the file I intended to edit from the command line. For example, when I intended to edit a file called `text_file.txt`, I could type this command:

```
emacs text_file.txt
```

And emacs would startup with `text_file.txt` as the selected buffer. Now that I've specified `initial-buffer-choice`, regardless of what I say after `emacs`, emacs will always open the file specified in `custom-set-variables`, and *not* the file specified at command line. For example, the command

```
emacs text_file.txt
```

now opens `~/Programming/C++/<some project I'm working on>` instead of `text_file.txt`.

How can I over ride `initial-buffer-choice` so when I do specify which file to open, that file will open?

Comment: Could someone also help me out and add more tags to this question? I don't have enough reputation to create new tags, although some (`custom-set-variables` and `initial-buffer-choice`, perhaps) seem fitting to me.

Comment: IMHO, a tag named `initial-buffer-choice` would be far to specific. You'd probably be the only question with that tag for a very, very long time. Therefore, the tag isn't terribly useful.

Comment: @PythonNut I see. I should probably leave it to the meta and more experienced users to define tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens after Emacs opens to your choice of `initial-buffer-choice`?  If you then use `C-x b` do you see the file you specified on the command line as an available buffer to choose from?  And is it perhaps even the default (try `M-n` to see if it gets pulled immediately to the minibuffer)?

If yes, then it sounds like Emacs is doing what you told it to:

1. Visit the file you gave it on the command line.
2. Show the initial buffer that you chose.

And it's not hard to use `C-x b`.  If the file in question comes up as the default buffer to switch to, things are easier still.

If that is not what you see then this sounds like a bug to me. If you can repro the behavior starting from `emacs -Q` (with any other specific switches and settings specified as part of the recipe), then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Note too that you can try setting `initial-buffer-choice` to a *function* that picks up a command-line file argument and uses that as the buffer to show.

Comment: It turns out the specified files are opened. Like you said, I just have to `C-x b` to get to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function for that checks if the current buffer has a filename.

```el
(setq initial-buffer-choice
  (lambda ()
    (if (buffer-file-name)
      (current-buffer) ;; leave as-is
      (find-file "~/Programming/C++/<some project I'm working on>"))))
```

Fo a full example see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38709/2418).